# Building a Vagrantfile with Chef provisioning not working

Tags: ruby, vagrant, chef-infra

I'm trying to follow the following text tutorial and my setup breaks at the point where he types "bundle install", my setup did not install bundle so clearly there's something wrong with my Chef stuff - https://gorails.com/guides/using-vagrant-for-rails-development

edit: Why was this question downvoted? Did I fail to provide some background?

I ran the first two commands.

```
vagrant plugin install vagrant-vbguest
vagrant plugin install vagrant-librarian-chef-nochef
```

I created a folder and made a Cheffile and Vagrantfile like so:

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"

Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|
    # Use Ubuntu 14.04 Trusty Tahr 64-bit as our operating system
    config.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64"

    # Configurate the virtual machine to use 2GB of RAM
    config.vm.provider :virtualbox do |vb|
        vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--memory", "2048"]
    end

    # Forward the Rails server default port to the host
    config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 3000, host: 3000

    # Use Chef Solo to provision our virtual machine
    config.vm.provision :chef_solo do |chef|
        chef.cookbooks_path = "cookbooks"

        chef.add_recipe "apt"
        chef.add_recipe "nodejs"
        chef.add_recipe "ruby_build"
        chef.add_recipe "rbenv::vagrant"
        chef.add_recipe "rbenv::user"
        chef.add_recipe "vim"
        chef.add_recipe "mysql::server"
        chef.add_recipe "mysql::client"

        # Install Ruby 2.2.1 and Bundler
        # Set an empty root password for MySQL to make things simple
        chef.json = {
            rbenv: {
                user_installs: [{
                    user: 'vagrant',
                    rubies: ["2.2.1"],
                    global: "2.2.1",
                    gems: {
                        "2.2.1" => [
                            { name: "bundler" }
                        ]
                    }
                }]
            },
            mysql: {
                server_root_password: ''
            }
        }
    end
end
```

Cheffile

```
site "http://community.opscode.com/api/v1"

cookbook 'apt'
cookbook 'build-essential'
cookbook 'mysql', '5.5.3'
cookbook 'ruby_build'
cookbook 'nodejs'
cookbook 'rbenv', git: 'https://github.com/aminin/chef-rbenv'
cookbook 'vim'
```

I have spent 3 days so far fiddling with this all day and night and I cannot get it to work. I launch my vagrant box and bundler is not installed so I can't bundle install.

Clearly the chef.json is not working. I have tried pouring over the error output, I've been googling and have hundreds of tabs open, at this point I am completely lost.

1. In my chef.json, how does that work? How do I begin to find out how to craft my own chef.json? I don't understand it, how do I know to write `user_installs` for example?
2. Is there a difference between the following:

a) `config.vm.provision :chef_solo do |chef|`

b) `config.vm.provision "chef solo" do |chef|`

3. I can't even Google anything related to Chef and cookbooks because I get cooking results, you know, for FOOD.

Comment: re: "How do I know to write user_installs": see https://github.com/fnichol/chef-rbenv

Comment: how is what i have in my post the same as `node.default['rbenv']['user_installs'] ` ?

Comment: the `node.default['rbenv' ]['user_installs']` will be parsed and transform to a hash, the json you give is loaded and merged into this hash with a highler level of precedence. See [this doc on attributes](https://docs.chef.io/attributes.html)

Answer (score 0):

Ahoy. There are a lot of questions up there.. so I'll try to go 1 at a time

*) Locally, did you install chef-client or chef dk?
Chefclient will not have bundler, where are chefdk does. It's also generally a smoother experience.

If you are using chef-client. You'll have to get bundler `gem install bundler`
If you are using chefdk. You'll either add chefdk ruby to your path, use temporary environment settings (`eval "$(chef shell-init bash)"`) or just use `chef exec bundle ...`

*) Semi unrelated. But the comments on that blog go way back to 10+ months ago. I suggest you take a look at the https://learn.chef.io/index.html for the latest tutorials

*) chef_solo and 'chef solo' are different things. `:chef_solo` is a symbol. Think of it as thing that has special meaning within vagrant language. `chef solo` would have no meaning - a) it has a space in it, so it would be two different things - either variables (undefined in your example) or "chef solo" a string, which would have no meaning to the provisioner.

*) for googling chef related results, I suggest using http://docs.chef.io or including the name of the tool 'chef vagrant nil error'

Finally, applause for going off and learning this toolset. It's awesome, but a whole new universe.